# Как при помощи api wordpress можно реализовать этот запрос?

Tags: wordpress, api, запрос

```
function get_all_cards_of_game($id, $num)
{

global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}posts` WHERE `ID` IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta where `meta_key`='_game')
    AND post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' ";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, OBJECT ); $s= array();
    $rr=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($results);$i++)
    {


        while (list($key, $val) = each($results[$i])) 
        {


            if($key=='ID')  {


                    $arr = get_field('game',$val);

                    if($arr[0]->ID == $id)
                    {
                        $rr[]=$results[$i];
                        break;
                    }
            }


        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал прочитать про `WP_Query`([офф.источник](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)). В общем, чтобы получить конкретные посты с метаключами, вам достаточно выполнить очень простые операции, несколько примеров ниже (как упростить Ваш код):

```
// Укажем, какие посты нам нужны
$params = [
    'post_type'      => 'post', // Пост тип
    'posts_per_page' => - 1, // Количество постов которые нам нужны(лимит), -1 - все
    'post_status'    => 'publish',  // По статусу, в данном случае опубликованные
    // Получим посты с конкретными метаключами
    'meta_query'     => [
        [
            'key'     => '_game', // Нужный нам ключ
            'compare' => 'EXISTS' // Сравнение, если существует
        ]
    ]
];

$list = new WP_Query( $params );

if ( $list->have_posts() ) {
    // Если посты найдены
    // Мы нашли что-то, давайте для примера получим ID всех постов
    $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $list->posts, 'ID' );
    // Также можно запустить (цикл) вывод всех названий постов, можно делать что угодно, так как у нас есть данные о каждом конкретно найденном посте
    while ( $list->have_posts() ) {
        $list->the_post(); // Установим указатель для удобства работы 
        the_title(); // Выведем заголовок
    }
} else {
    // Если ничего не нашлось
}
wp_reset_query(); // Обнулим запрос, чтобы ничего не поломать на странице дальше
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вот эту часть еще бы встроить в запрос сразу:   if($key=='ID')  {


                    $arr = get_field('game',$val);

                    if($arr[0]->ID == $id)
                    {
                        $rr[]=$results[$i];
                        break;
                    }
            }

Comment: @user10803259 Не зная и видя(не описано), зачем вам нужен ключ и что Вы собираетесь делать трудно ответить на вопрос. На примере выше из БД выберет посты только если есть ключ `_game`, далее например, чтобы внутри перебора получить значение поля для поста, есть очень много хуков, если с помошью WP то, например, `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_game',true)`, если так как у Вас(у вас плагин установленый ACF) -  `get_field( 'game' )`. Будет получено значение поля `_game` для конкретного поста в цикле.

Comment: Вот это оно. От чистого sql ушел, от полей базы отвязался. Еще раз спасибо - помогли.

Comment: @user10803259 Советую читать туториалы для начинающих, на русском тут (https://wp-kama.ru)

Comment: @user10803259 и ещё. Ответ хорош тем, что результаты функций WordPress эффективно кешируются. А код в вопросе - нет.

Comment: Ага, очень верное замечание. Учту.